# Installation of the oracle database into different drive

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

is it mandatory to install the Oracle database in C drive? I am trying to install it in F drive but is aborting in the middle of installation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can install it on any disk that has enough space. We've had it on D and E drives, no problem.

Comment: you can install Oracle database in  any drive.What is the exact error you are getting during installation?

Comment: The short answer is: no, it's not. If you want to get help with your installation error then you need to post the complete details: show us all the steps to reproduce the error, post the complete error message.